# How to read from data line from json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

So im trying to get account id from world of tanks api and im getting `{'status': 'ok', 'meta': {'count': 1}, 'data': [{'nickname': '<Nickname>', 'account_id': <account id in int>}]}`, but i dont know how to get the account id value. It can give more values in data part but i only want the first one.

Im getting that json line using this code

```py
fr = requests.post(
            "https://api.worldoftanks.eu/wot/account/list/",
            data={'application_id': <wargaming aplication id>, 'search': <user nickname>}
            )
        print(fr.json())
```

And im trying to get account_id from this part `'data': [{'nickname': '<Nickname>', 'account_id': <account id in int>}`. I only know how to list everything from `data` part using `print(fr.json()[data])`

Comment: What have you tried or researched so far? Have you parsed the JSON already? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: First this is not valid json because it contains single quotes while json uses double quotes. Next, if it is a plain Python object, then you can just access the elements.

Comment: Can you share some code on how youre getting that json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use python's built-in [json library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).
Specifically, the `json.loads()` function. This takes in a string and returns a dict. However, as mentioned in the comments, this won't work right off the bat with your data, as it's invalid json.

```
import json

s = "{'status': 'ok', 'meta': {'count': 1}, 'data': [{'nickname': '<Nickname>', 'account_id': 1234}]}"

s = s.replace("\'", "\"") # Format it correctly

obj = json.loads(s)

account_id = obj["data"][0]["account_id"]
```